# Passing values from config file directly as command line parameters

Tags: powershell, control-m

I have a PowerShell script which needs to invoked via controlM.
Sample invocation looks like

```
powershell -NoLogo -NonInteractive -Command "D:\path\to\Whatever.ps1 -param1 %%PARAM1 -param2 %%PARAM2"
```

The value for param2 is a CSV like '1111111,2222222' and typically spans nearly .5 million chars long.

**Issue:** There is a limitation in controlM that a max of 4000 chars can be set for a variable via the controlM interface.

So, the workaround I can think of is to have a wrapper script (which will now be hooked to controlM instead) which will invoke `Whatever.ps1` after reading config file. Something like:

`sample.ini`:

```
[General]
param1=value1
param2='1111111,2222222'
```

But I am not sure if writing a wrapper script, consume the log output from exising `Whatever.ps1` etc. is the best idea.
So, just wondering if there is a way so that values from the config file can be directly fed to `Whatever.ps1`. Something like

```
powershell -NoLogo -NonInteractive -Command "D:\path\to\Whatever.ps1 -param1 sample.ini[param2] -param2 sample.ini[param2]"
```

Comment: Add an INI parser to your script and pass it the filename and an array with the key names as parameters.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Whatever.ps1 does a very specific task. I would rather not like to add a parser in it, to bypass the limitation imposed by controlM, as it is completely unrelated to the task it performs. That is where I started to think of a wrapper script which will instead parse & invoke Whatever.ps1. Thanks for your prompt response.

Comment: Whether you build the parser into that script or into another script inovking that script is irrelevant. The procedure is essentially the same.